# Work with local database file (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

How to change a database folder to folder create by me in App folder with existing database file. Thanks for help.

```
public class SQLite_WinPhone81 : ISQLite
{
    public SQLite_WinPhone81()
    {
    }
    #region ISQLite implementation
    public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var sqliteFilename = "xx.db3";
        string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);

        var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

        // Return the database connection 
        return conn;


    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Unclear. You seem to have most of it already, and I don't get what you want differently. Be clear, specify actual and expected results.

Comment: I have connect my app with existing database file on folder db (db\xx.db3). Now file xx.db3 is in LocalFolder.Path

Comment: Well, when you have connected then everything is OK, right?

Comment: yes it's ok ...

Comment: I have copy file with db folder to LocalFolder.Path in phone when app is run.

Comment: And where is that db folder?   Copy on startup, shutdown, some other time else? You're still very short on details here. When English is difficult, post more (pseudo) code.